# Output the value of a struct member using the (.) operator gives different results than -> operator, why?

Tags: c

Something strange happens when I try to output the value of a struct member using the (.) operator gives different results than -> operator, here is the code

```
typedef struct MonitoredDns
{
int16               dnLength;
char                setDn[26];
tDeviceId           setId;
tDeviceId           acquiredSetId;
tCallId             activeCallId;
tCallId             selectedCallId;
} MonitoredDns;

MonitoredDns* pMonitoredDn = (MonitoredDns*) malloc(sizeof(MonitoredDns));
MonitoredDns dnStruct = *pMonitoredDn;
mbMonitorDeviceBegin(dn, &dnStruct.setId);

//Now print setId value set by the mbMonitorDeviceBegin function using the two following methods
//%hu is for unsigned short as I think, setId is a tDevice which is uInt16
printf("before(1) AddDnToMonitoredDns SetID = %hu\n", pMonitoredDn->setId);
printf("before(2) AddDnToMonitoredDns SetID = %hu\n", dnStruct.setId);
```

Comment: You're printing the members of *different* instances...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MonitoredDns dnStruct = *pMonitoredDn;
```

After executing this line, `dnStruct` is not the same thing as `*pMonitoredDn`, it's a *copy* of `*pMonitoredDn`. You then call your method that modifies the copy, and the original `malloc`-ed version is still unchanged.

Try this instead, this version will show that the `.` and `->` have the same result. However, this version isn't the same as what you had, because the lifetime of the memory pointed to by `pMonitoredDn` is now only as long as the method lasts, whereas the `malloc`-ed memory would last until `free`-ed.

```
MonitoredDns dnStruct;
MonitoredDns* pMonitoredDn = &dnStruct;
mbMonitorDeviceBegin(dn, &dnStruct.setId);

//Now print setId value set by the mbMonitorDeviceBegin function using the two following methods
//%hu is for unsigned short as I think, setId is a tDevice which is uInt16
printf("before(1) AddDnToMonitoredDns SetID = %hu\n", pMonitoredDn->setId);
printf("before(2) AddDnToMonitoredDns SetID = %hu\n", dnStruct.setId);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you make a copy of the empty structure.

Then you call a function that modifies the copy.

Then you wonder why the copy is not the same as the original.